# Windows Store Universal App - Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, dependency-properties, win-universal-app

actually i am developing a universal app for Windows and Windows Phone.
Within that app i am using dependency properties to assign data to properties of custom user controls in XAML. The problem is that the compiler says he is not able to find the property were i would like to bind data to.

The button definition looks like the following.

```
public sealed partial class RulerButton : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackendProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Backend", typeof(GlobalData), 
        typeof(RulerButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public GlobalData Backend
    {
        get { return (GlobalData)GetValue(BackendProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackendProperty, value); }
    }

    public RulerButton()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I use this button within my main page like this.

```
<btn:RulerButton Backend="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=BackendSource}"/>
```

Then the compiler says `Unknown Member "Backend" in Element "RulerButton".`

If have used the same approach earlier in other projects (Normal WPF-Windows applications) and it worked well. So i think the problem is related to universal app projects.

All other questions i have found could not solve my problem. 
I would be appreciated if someone could give me a hint.

greets

**Edit**

Well i actually have solved the problem. But i think it is very curious. Beside the `RulerButton` i have many other controls where i added the same dependency properties. On some of them i did not add the normal property `Backend` yet. Cause i first wanted to make the `RulerButton` work. After completing these controls so that each of them has a `BackendProperty` and `Backend` attribute, all errors were gone.

anyway thanks for your help guys

Comment: The DP is for `RulerButton` but your XAML is using `PreviewButton`?

Comment: Oh im sorry, a copy mistake.

Comment: Did you try recompiling?

Comment: And the compiler still says `Unknown Member "Backend" in Element "PreviewButton"`? Or is that also a copy error?

Comment: Is that a compiler error or IntelliSense error?

Comment: By WPF - do you mean WinRT/XAML? WPF isn't supported in Store apps.

Comment: Yes the error still exist. Cleaning and rebuilding the project changes nothing. I think its a compiler error because I am not able to start the application. And yes I mean WinRT/XAML. Did not know that there is a difference sry.

Comment: How can i close this question?

Comment: Write an answer to your question explaining how you solved it. You can do so by clicking the buton at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i actually have solved the problem. But i think it is very curious. Beside the RulerButton i have many other controls where i added the same dependency properties. On some of them i did not add the normal property Backend yet. Cause i first wanted to make the RulerButton work. After completing these controls so that each of them has a BackendProperty and Backend attribute, all errors were gone.